# UILabel value does not update in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am creating custom cells and updating some `UILabel`s every time when that view appears.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

       UILabel *lblFacingValue = nil;
       static NSUInteger const kFacingLabelTag = 7;

      CGFloat LeftLabelWidth = 130.0;

      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
      ClientState *clientState = [ClientState sharedInstance];
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil) 
   {
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

       if(indexPath.row == 0)
       {
           lblFacingValue = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(246, -11, LeftLabelWidth, (cell.contentView.frame.size.height))] autorelease];
           lblFacingValue.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:21];           
           lblFacingValue.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
           lblFacingValue.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
           lblFacingValue.tag = kFacingLabelTag;        
           lblFacingValue.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
           [cell.contentView addSubview:lblFacingValue];
       }
    }
   lblFacingValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", clientState.Direction];
}
```

But the problem is that it contains the value which I assign first time and do not update it when I open that view. that view is in tab.

It did not update the value of **lblFacingValue** and skip the check

> if (cell == nil)

after first time. but do not update lblFacingValue.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it contains the value which I assign first time and do not update it when I open that view.'? How do you update the cells? EDIT: ok, got it.

Comment: You mean that you have 2 labels - one of them should be updated and the other one shouldn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azhar, I think you forget to set the lblFacingValue variable to the actual UILabel object when the call to dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier does not return nil. You should add:

```
lblFacingValue = [cell viewWithTag:kFacingLabelTag];
```

before calling

```
lblFacingValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", clientState.Direction];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Keep one thing in mind, when cell is nil, you **construct** the cell. Don't assign values there. Just create subviews etc.

This code should fix it. Also see my comments in it.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   
    static NSUInteger const kFacingLabelTag = 7; //This should rather be a #define ..   
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

       if(indexPath.row == 0)
       {
           CGFloat LeftLabelWidth = 130.0;
           UILabel *lblFacingValue = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(246, -11, LeftLabelWidth, (cell.contentView.frame.size.height))] autorelease];
           lblFacingValue.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:21];           
           lblFacingValue.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
           lblFacingValue.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
           lblFacingValue.tag = kFacingLabelTag;        
           lblFacingValue.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
           [cell.contentView addSubview:lblFacingValue];
       }
    }

    //now, we might be reusing the cell, so in either case, pick the label
    //and edit the value.

    ClientState *clientState = [ClientState sharedInstance];
    UILabel *theLabel = (UILabel*) [cell.contentView viewForTag:kFacingLabelTag];    
    theLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", clientState.Direction];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget a piece where you get the label by it tag if you do dequeue a cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    UILabel *lblFacingValue = nil;
    static NSUInteger const kFacingLabelTag = 7;

    CGFloat LeftLabelWidth = 130.0;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ClientState *clientState = [ClientState sharedInstance];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            lblFacingValue = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(246, -11, LeftLabelWidth, (cell.contentView.frame.size.height))] autorelease];
            lblFacingValue.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:21];           
            lblFacingValue.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            lblFacingValue.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            lblFacingValue.tag = kFacingLabelTag;        
            lblFacingValue.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblFacingValue];
        }
    } else {
        lblFacingValue = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:kFacingLabelTag];
    }

    lblFacingValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", clientState.Direction];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your specially configured cell has the same cell identifier as the others,

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
```

So the system doesn't differentiate when dequeuing cells between your special cell and normal cells. You should create a different cell identifier for the special cell, and dequeue using that when indexPath.row == 0;

Comment: are you sure about this?